# PostgreSQL round(v numeric, s int)

Tags: postgresql, floating-point, rounding

Which [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking) does Postgres [`round(v numeric, s int)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-math.html) use?

1. Round half up
2. Round half down
3. Round half away from zero
4. Round half towards zero
5. Round half to even
6. Round half to odd

I'm looking for documentation reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How exactly work round function in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49879824/how-exactly-work-round-function-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, I don't see any hint of this in the documentation, but [a look at the code](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/backend_2utils_2adt_2numeric_8c_source.html#l06406) indicates it's using *round half away from zero*; the `carry` is always added to `digits`, thereby increasing the absolute value of the variable, regardless of what its `sign` is.  A simple experiment (psql 9.1) confirms this:

```
test=# CREATE TABLE nvals (v numeric(5,2));
CREATE TABLE
test=# INSERT INTO nvals (v) VALUES (-0.25), (-0.15), (-0.05), (0.05), (0.15), (0.25);
INSERT 0 6
test=# SELECT v, round(v, 1) FROM nvals;
   v   | round 
-------+-------
 -0.25 |  -0.3
 -0.15 |  -0.2
 -0.05 |  -0.1
  0.05 |   0.1
  0.15 |   0.2
  0.25 |   0.3
(6 rows)
```

Interesting, because `round(v dp)` uses *half even*:

```
test=# create table vals (v double precision);
CREATE TABLE
test=# insert into vals (v) VALUES (-2.5), (-1.5), (-0.5), (0.5), (1.5), (2.5);
INSERT 0 6
test=# select v, round(v) from vals;
  v   | round 
------+-------
 -2.5 |    -2
 -1.5 |    -2
 -0.5 |    -0
  0.5 |     0
  1.5 |     2
  2.5 |     2
(6 rows)
```

The latter behavior is almost certainly platform-dependent, since it looks like [it uses rint(3) under the hood](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/float_8c_source.html#l01273).

You could always implement a different rounding scheme if necessary.  See [Tometzky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30546518/519015) for examples.

Comment: Your `round_odd_two(nnum numeric)` is bad: `round_odd_two(0.001)` is `0.01`, should be `0.00`.

Comment: @Tometzky you are correct.  I realized what I had implemented was *round odd* not round *half* odd.  I am replacing my example with a reference to your answer.

Answer (score 11):

It's not documented, so it can change.

Here are my `round_half_even(numeric,integer)`:

```
create or replace function round_half_even(val numeric, prec integer)
    returns numeric
as $$
declare
    retval numeric;
    difference numeric;
    even boolean;
begin
    retval := round(val,prec);
    difference := retval-val;
    if abs(difference)*(10::numeric^prec) = 0.5::numeric then
        even := (retval * (10::numeric^prec)) % 2::numeric = 0::numeric;
        if not even then
            retval := round(val-difference,prec);
        end if;
    end if;
    return retval;
end;
$$ language plpgsql immutable strict;
```

And `round_half_odd(numeric,integer)`:

```
create or replace function round_half_odd(val numeric, prec integer)
    returns numeric
as $$
declare
    retval numeric;
    difference numeric;
    even boolean;
begin
    retval := round(val,prec);
    difference := retval-val;
    if abs(difference)*(10::numeric^prec) = 0.5::numeric then
        even := (retval * (10::numeric^prec)) % 2::numeric = 0::numeric;
        if even then
            retval := round(val-difference,prec);
        end if;
    end if;
    return retval;
end;
$$ language plpgsql immutable strict;
```

They manage about 500000 invocations per second, 6 times slower than a standard `round(numeric,integer)`. They also work for zero and for negative precision.