# How exactly work round function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

How round function in postgresql actually work? 
Query below demonstrate odd behavior

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/IHQ94614)**

```
select
    val
    ,Round(x.val::NUMERIC) as NUMERIC_Round
    ,Round(x.val::DOUBLE PRECISION) as DOUBLE_Round
from
    generate_series(-10.5,10.5,0.5) as x(val)
```

When `Val` take '10.5', '6.5', '4.5' etc. result of round is different.

[Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html) say that 
for double precision:

```
 round(dp or numeric)   (same as input) round to nearest integer
```

for numeric:

```
round(v numeric, s int) numeric round to s decimal places
```

This does not explain why result for '10.5', '6.5', '4.5' are different.
What am i doing wrong?
May be some detailed explanation can help to understand round function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-numeric.html) in the documentation indicates the differences in rounding between different data types:

> The types `decimal` and `numeric` are equivalent. Both types are part of the SQL standard.
>
> When rounding values, the `numeric` type rounds ties away from zero, while (on most machines) the `real` and `double precision` types round ties to the nearest even number. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT x,
>     round(x::numeric) AS num_round,
>     round(x::double precision) AS dbl_round
> FROM generate_series(-3.5, 3.5, 1) as x;
>
>   x   | num_round | dbl_round
> ------+-----------+-----------
>  -3.5 |        -4 |        -4
>  -2.5 |        -3 |        -2
>  -1.5 |        -2 |        -2
>  -0.5 |        -1 |        -0
>   0.5 |         1 |         0
>   1.5 |         2 |         2
>   2.5 |         3 |         2
>   3.5 |         4 |         4
> (8 rows)
> ```

There was some discussion on the pgsql-hackers mailing list about the changes [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAEZATCWGaeLoHdsWk7Yz4jFMFOH8f%3DcapC6SjMa0HYBK5_xu5Q%40mail.gmail.com#CAEZATCWGaeLoHdsWk7Yz4jFMFOH8f=capC6SjMa0HYBK5_xu5Q@mail.gmail.com).