# How to use Banker's Rounding Mode in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, rounding, bankers-rounding

I have tried to search, but I can't seem to find an implementation of Banker's Rounding Mode in Postgresql.  I found this thread in which there was an effort to create an implementation in T-SQL https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic246556-8-1.aspx.

For example, Andrew Vasylevskyy nicely gives some examples
Examples of banker's rounding (results of Math.Round in .NET):

```
Math.Round(3.454,2) -> 3.45
Math.Round(3.455,2) -> 3.46
Math.Round(3.445,2) -> 3.44
Math.Round(3.456,2) -> 3.46
```

Based on this thread [PostgreSQL round(v numeric, s int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613702/postgresql-roundv-numeric-s-int) it appears that there is not a way to configure the default `round()` function to use a specific mode and that it does not use Banker's Rounding Mode.  I do see there is a `round_half_even` or a `round_half_odd` but it is my understanding it is not the same as Banker's rounding.

Has anyone created a function that does this or is there an extension out there that can be added to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) and [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) say Banker's Rounding is round-half-to-even.

I don't know if a Postgres extension which implements alternative rounding, which is surprising. Best I've found is [this answer with implementations as functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30546518/14660).

Comment: Thanks for the Wiki and Java links.  Sounds like Banker's Rounding is round-half-to-even.